# Android studio : how to reach "id" field when using quick edition (F2) on View in Layout Editor

Tags: android, graphical-layout-editor, android-studio-import

I've discovered a very cool feature in android studio: when pressing "F2" while a Button is selected in layout editor (it's an example, i haven't tested for others View but i think it's the same thing), a small window appear that permit to quick change "text" and "id" properties without the need to browse properties palette (see screenshot).

But i don't know how to reach the "id" property only with keyboard. The TAB key doesn't work in this context, so i've to click on it : it's time consuming.

Someone has an idea ?

[image]

Comment: Tab works for me (Studio 1.3, OS X Yosemite).

Comment: Upgrade to the latest version. TAB works.

Comment: I'm already to the latest version (1.4). But i'm on Linux Mint 17.2. A bug in this environment ? When i'm in the field "id" and press TAB, i return good to "text" property. But if i press again on TAB, the quick edit disappear.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry : the bug didn't occur anymore since i've relaunched Android Studio today. Perhaps it was due to a specific configuration of android or linux. I don't know.
It's a good new for me...